# Sending ajax request between https

Tags: ajax, node.js, angularjs, http

I'm using angular to send ajax request to nodejs file, and I'm having this error,

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:3000/SetUser. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

sending it from index.html to `https://localhost:3000/SetUser`, and direction what could go wrong and how can I allow that access of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`?

-- edit:
I googled and I found this lines

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
```

but I still get the same error, this is the current `app.post`

```
app.post('/SetUser', function(req, res) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    console.log("New user added ", req.body);
});
```

thanks!

Comment: Make both of servers http or https

Comment: I need one as HTTPS and one as HTTP I'm looking for a solution for the current situation.

Comment: I decided to do what you said and make them both to run as HTTPS, but I still get an `not allowed access` error

Comment: After you do your `res.header()`s you need to do `res.end()` to send a response containing those headers you just set.

Comment: Maybe your missing res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

Comment: I tried both of what you 2 said, and still same error,
http://pastebin.com/i3vrycG1

Comment: it must be an error that come from the server side ? not sure from which part it comes from